# Dictionary service

Tags: dictionary, apache-tika

Is there a service I can call programatically to determine what language the UTF-8 encoded word belongs to?

I tried using Apache Tika and it does not work at all.

```
LanguageDetector detector = new OptimaizeLangDetector().loadModels();
final LanguageResult result = detector.detect(s);

return result.getLanguage();
```

This code returns German (de) for word "Find" and French for word "out".

Comment: Apache Tika's language detection generally works best on longer runs, rather than specific words, mostly due to the statistical basis. What happens if you give Tika loads of text instead?

Comment: I have mixed language text so I am not sure how it will be handled as a whole.Is there service or library that can detect language of individual word?

Comment: You might have more luck on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead of here for that